# Master m3u8 file does not list streams

Tags: ffmpeg, m3u8, ffmpeg-python

I have a video and I want to transcode it into hls using ffmpeg-python.
It works well with a video which has an audio stream.
But does not list stream playlists in master.m3u8 when I give a video file without audio as an input.

problem: master.m3u8 is not listing stream, only contains:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
```

expected:

```
#EXTM3U
#EXT-X-VERSION:6
#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=415800,RESOLUTION=1280x720,CODECS="avc1.64001f,mp4a.40.2"
prefix_stream_0.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=105600,RESOLUTION=768x432,CODECS="avc1.64001e,mp4a.40.2"
prefix_stream_1.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=105600,RESOLUTION=640x360,CODECS="avc1.64001e,mp4a.40.2"
prefix_stream_2.m3u8

#EXT-X-STREAM-INF:BANDWIDTH=52800,RESOLUTION=426x240,CODECS="avc1.640015,mp4a.40.2"
prefix_stream_3.m3u8
```